# Specifying test rows for backtest and machine learning

Tags: python

I want to use a machine learning to predict the price movement of an asset. so far I got the data and results. now I want to back test the model. the premise is very simple: just buy whenever the predicted value is 1 and hold. I want to apply predicting model and iterate over the testing rows from the bottom up to the specified number, check whether the predicted output matches the corresponding label (the label here is -1,1), then do some calculation.

here is the code:

```
def backtest():
    x = df[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vol']]
    y = df['label']
    z = np.array(df['log_ret'].values)

test_size = 366
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)
rf.fit(x[:-test_size],y[:-test_size])

invest_amount = 1000
trade_qty = 0
correct_count = 0

for i in range(1, test_size):
    if rf.predict(x[-i])[0] == y[-i]:
    correct_count += 1

if rf.predict(x[-i])[0] == 1:
    invest_return = invest_amount + (invest_amount * (z[-i]/100))
    trade_qty += 1


print('accuracy:', (correct_count/test_size)*100)
print('total trades:', trade_qty)
print('profits:', invest_return)

backtest()
```

So far I am stuck on this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: -1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-feab89792f26> in <module>
     22 
     23 for i in range(1, test_size):
---> 24     if rf.predict(x[-i])[0] == y[-i]:
     25         correct_count += 1
     26 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: -1
```

Comment: is your code correctly idented inside the question? If not, could you please rectify this?

Comment: ok I just did some editing. I think this is ok now? please let me know. I am not very familiar with the formating

Comment: It seems still incorrect, but I think I was able to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code below, solves the problem with a few modifications:

```
def backtest():
    x = df[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vol']]
    y = df['label']
    z = np.array(df['log_ret'].values)

    test_size = 366
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)
    rf.fit(x[:-test_size],y[:-test_size])

    invest_amount = 1000
    trade_qty = 0
    correct_count = 0

    for i in range(1, test_size)[::-1]:
        if rf.predict(x[x.index == i])[0] == y[i]:
            correct_count += 1

        if rf.predict(x[x.index == i])[0] == 1:
            invest_return = invest_amount + (invest_amount * (z[i]/100))
            trade_qty += 1

    print('accuracy:', (correct_count/test_size)*100)
    print('total trades:', trade_qty)
    print('profits:', invest_return)

backtest()
```

**Explaining the modifications:**

1. Accessing the dataframe row by filtering the index `x[x.index ==
   i]`;
2. Modifying the negative index for a backwards range with fewer adaptations `range(1, test_size)[::-1]`;

**Generating a test case:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

data = {'open': np.random.rand(1000), 
        'high': np.random.rand(1000), 
        'low': np.random.rand(1000), 
        'close': np.random.rand(1000), 
        'vol': np.random.rand(1000),
        'log_ret': np.random.rand(1000),
        'label': np.random.choice([-1,1], 1000)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This produces the following result:

```
>> backtest()
accuracy: 99.72677595628416
total trades: 181
profits: 1006.8351193358026
```